# drawing routes view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, dictionary

how can i  draw routes on a map. This is easily solved though by placing a custom UIView over the map that acts as the map delegate but didn't how can i do this, and  how to take a series of CLLocation coordinates and plot them on the map, regardless of the location the user pans to or how far they have zoomed in.Give some hint to solve this or give some sample code to do this

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In ios4 apple has made some nice additions for this. Look at mkoverlay protocol and mkoverlayview.
You'll find an example here
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136

Comment: thanks But i need CLLocation, And The line must  move with  CLLocation as the user move location will change according to that line also move .This location also get store into route.csv file and when ever i want to see the  past journey  it must show that

Comment: Still: if you want to draw routs on the map this should be the way to go. The map then takes care of showing them or hiding them according to the user location

Comment: Thanks once again for replaying me .Can it work on simulator or it work on iphone .If i want  store this data into sqlite data how can i do this.

Comment: This will work on The Simulator technically. Though core location will not generate useful location data. Regarding your storage question : can you be mor specific or show what you have tried so far ?